# Python list-comprehension for words that do not consist solely of digits

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

At a high level, what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
given a list of words, return all the words that do not consist solely of digits
```

My first thought of how to do that is:

```
import string
result = []
for word in words:
    for each_char in word:
        if each_char not in string.digit:
            result.append(word)
            break
return result
```

This works fine. To be more Pythonic, I figured - list comprehensions, right? So:

```
return [word for word in words for char in word if not char in string.digits]
```

Unfortunately, this adds a copy of `word` to the result for each character that isn't a digit. So for `f(['foo'])`, I end up with `['foo', 'foo', 'foo']`.

Is there a clever way to do what I'm trying to do? My current solution is to just write an `is_all_digits` function, and say `[word for word in words if not is_all_digits(word)]`. My general understanding is that list comprehensions allow this sort of operation to be declarative, and the helper function is plenty declarative for me; just curious as to whether there's some clever way to make it one compound statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: as a rule, it's better to give working code examples.  (`return` is a keyword and so can't be used as a variable name; you mean `string.digits`, not `strings.digits`; and you changed the variable name from `each_char` to `char`.)

Comment: Do you also have negative numbers?

Comment: I'm okay letting negative numbers through; it's a language-processing context, and I'm just trying to get noise out. In general, though, good point, and that's probably points for the isdigit() approach

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just check the whole string for `isdigit()`:

```
>>> words = ['foo', '123', 'foo123']
>>> [word for word in words if not word.isdigit()]
['foo', 'foo123']
```

Or, turn the logic other way and use `any()`:

```
>>> [word for word in words if any(not char.isdigit() for char in word)]
['foo', 'foo123']
```

`any()` would stop on the first non-digit character for a word and return `True`.

Comment: Excellent and more concise than the answer I was going to post.

Comment: Yep, good call. This totally works for me, though one reservation - performance-wise, it has to go through the entire string, whereas it could be possible to make the is_not_digit determination from the first character. Now I'm curious, so I'll do some actual benchmarking with my specific dataset to see if it makes a difference. :)

Comment: @mfrankli well, according to what you are aiming for - you need to filter out words that consist of digits *solely* - this means that you should go from the beginning to the end of word anyway. Consider `123foo` example.

Comment: @mfrankli: That's probably what `isdigit()` actually does.

Comment: doesn't isdigit() have to check every single character for digit-ness? while all I actually need is to find the *first* non-digit

Comment: @mfrankli yeah, you are right that you can check for the first non-digit too, please see the update.

Comment: yep, I knew there was something clever! the any() was the bit of python I didn't know about. thanks!

Comment: @mfrankli yeah, too late for my brain to think properly, sorry. And, it's actually interesting what solution is faster and what the performance gain is.

Comment: @mfrankli: `isdigit` will stop on the first non-digit too, since one non-digit lets it know the result is `False`.

Comment: that's completely true. this is what I get for thinking about this stuff late at night.

Comment: Wow, that's compact! +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

```
filter(lambda _: not _.isdigit(), iterable)
```

Example:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda _: not _.isdigit(), ["hello", "good1", "1234"]))
['hello', 'good1']
```